# Why is my vagrant vvv on Windows 8 not running?

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox

I set everything up correctly and even was able to access vvv.dev. But after I used vagrant halt at night and tried to do vagrant up in the morning, I am not able to access any of the development websites.

I am able to start the virtual server fine. This is a dump of what I see in the cmder terminal when I do vagrant up.

```
λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  vvv  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  vvv.dev  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  local.wordpress.dev  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  local.wordpress-trunk.dev  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  src.wordpress-develop.dev  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  build.wordpress-develop.dev  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
==> default: adding to (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  192.168.50.4 local.wordpress.dev local.wordpress-trunk.dev  # VAGRANT: d40ca6129049f2b46ad0834feb482d92 (default) / ccbbf797-c9b1-49d1-a887-a4d8caec2676
C:/Users/hola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82:in `initialize': Permission denied - C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/Users/hola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82:in `open'
        from C:/Users/hola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82:in `addToHosts'
        from C:/Users/hola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:42:in `addHostEntries'
        from C:/Users/hola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/Action/UpdateHosts.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_guest_additions.rb:49:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/wait_for_communicator.rb:71:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/boot.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/sane_defaults.rb:38:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/set_hostname.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/forward_ports.rb:31:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:121:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:84:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:160:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:68:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:214:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:191:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my (very limited) knowledge, every time you halt Vagrant it removes all of it's entries in the hosts file. Simply, on windows Vagrant needs an elevated terminal so it can edit the hosts file.

If you didn't run your terminal as an administrator, try that first - hope that works!

Comment: Yeah, but it's not Vagrant itself, it's the `vagrant-hostsupdater` plugin: `C:/Users/hola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82:in 'initialize': Permission denied - C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts (Errno::EACCES)`